# What is meant by "number of characters extracted" in the std::ifstream gcount doc?

Tags: c++, ifstream, eof, getline, null-character

It is said in the documentation of the `ifstream::getline` method that:

> The number of characters successfully read and **stored** by this function can be accessed by calling member **gcount**. https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

> **In any case**, if count > 0, it then stores a null character CharT() into the next successive location of the array and **updates gcount()**. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

From both of the above resources documenting `ifstream::getline` it can be deduced that *gcount* is supposed to be changed even after encountering the end of file (EOF). That's due to the fact that *any case* includes the EOF case and we all know that an update is only an update if it changes the target record.

It is said in the documentation of `ifstream::gcount` method that it:

> Returns the number of characters extracted by the last unformatted input operation performed on the object.
> https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/

> Returns the number of characters extracted by the last unformatted input operation, or the maximum representable value of std::streamsize if the number is not representable.
> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount

If it's the number of characters extracted **from** the *ifstream*, then the CPlusPlus.com documentation of *getline* must be wrong as it states "characters successfully read and **stored**".

Also, the CppReference.com would be wrong, because it states that "in any case ... updates gcount()" but *gcount* is not updated when an EOF is encountered before the line end delimiter.

If it's the number of characters written into the array buffer argument of `ifstream::getline`, then the standard library has a bug. When during the execution of `ifstream::getline` the line ends prematurely with end-of-file (EOF), the null character is appended to the end of the array buffer but *gcount* is **not updated accordingly**.

Here is the code that exemplifies the dilemma.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " file\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::array<char, 10> buf;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(argv[1], std::ifstream::in);

    do {
        file.clear();
        file.getline(buf.data(), buf.size());
        std::streamsize gcount = file.gcount();

        if (file.bad() || gcount <= 0) {
            break;
        }

        if (!file.fail()) {
            std::cerr
                << "LINE: [" << buf.data() << "] gcount "
                << std::to_string(gcount) << ", strlen "
                << std::to_string(strlen(buf.data()))
                << (file.eof() ? " (EOF)\n" : "\n");

            continue;
        }

        // Buffer must have got full. Let's skip to the end of line.
        file.clear();
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    while (!file.eof() && !file.bad());

    file.close();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the output I get for a text file that **does not have a newline character in the end** of its last line.

```
LINE: [dgsagdsa] gcount 9, strlen 8
LINE: [test] gcount 5, strlen 4
LINE: [test123] gcount 8, strlen 7
LINE: [123test] gcount 8, strlen 7
LINE: [] gcount 1, strlen 0
LINE: [xxxxxxx] gcount 8, strlen 7
LINE: [yy] gcount 2, strlen 2 (EOF)
```

As you can see, there is a discrepancy between *gcount* and *strlen* on the last line of the output.

That said, let's come back to the main question now.

What is meant by the *number of characters extracted* in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) of `std::ifstream::gcount`?

The question has two parts to it.

1. What is meant by a "character"?
2. What is meant by "extraction"?

Is one character always one byte in this context? A unicode character could consist of multiple bytes. A line end sequence could consist of multiple bytes too (CR+LF). Could it ever happen (perhaps in the future) that *gcount* is increased by 1 but multiple bytes were *extracted*? Could it ever happen that *gcount* is increased by 1 but multiple bytes were *stored* in the array buffer?

Comment: what are the contents of the file?

Comment: this "discrepancy" is because `getline` reads either until it finds the delimiter or hits eof. And the delimiter is **not** written to the array. Not a bug.

Comment: `cplusplus.com` is wrong. I'd suggest using `cppreference.com`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

Comment: one issue may be that there is no EOF character

Comment: frankly I dont see the "dilemma". Number of bytes written is `gcount` unless extraction hit eof instead of the delimiter then it is gcount+1 because no delimiter was read (and then not written to the array)

Comment: out of curiosity, whats the actual problem that arises from this? Are you reading binary data that can contain `\0` in the middle? If not `strlen` is always right, no?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number where in the documentation is this gcount+1 ever mentioned?

Comment: nowhere, gcount is the number of extracted characters. period. Thats what it is. Also in your examples. EOF is not a character that is extracted, maybe thats your misunderstanding

Comment: 463035818_is_not_a_number then why do you post this as an answer? why don't you just agree that the documentation is flawed?

Comment: `gcount` counts the delimiter but that delimiter is not written to the array. `gcount` does not count `EOF` because `EOF` is not a character extracted from the stream. Both are not added to the array

Comment: because I do not get your point. Where is the documentation flawed?

Comment: @tkausl cppreference.com is wrong too. Just read what is written there. It says "In **any** case, if count > 0, it then stores a null character CharT() into the next successive location of the array and updates gcount()"

Comment: nobody else here sees the flaw that you claim to see

Comment: ooooh. You mean "The number of characters successfully read and stored by this function can be accessed by calling member gcount." from cpluscplus. Well, cplusplus is known to be inaccurate and somtimes outright wrong. Dont use it. Is there also something wrong with cppreference? I dont see it yet

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number cppreference has the same issue, worded differently.

Comment: i really think this should be closed

Comment: No it does not. Cppref say that gcount is the number of charcters extracted and thats what it is. EOF is not a character. the new line character is a character. And it is  not added to the array

Comment: @Hyena its not wrong as it does exactly that. `and updates gcount()` doesn't mean it adds one.

Comment: 463035818_is_not_a_number read the part where it says "**in any case**". Any case includes the EOF case, which means gcount is supposed to be updated!

Comment: also cplusplus says "A null character ('\0') is automatically appended to the written sequence if n is greater than zero, even if an empty string is extracted."

Comment: if you are super picky with wording then you will find a flaw in any text.

Comment: This is very much an issue and should not be closed because there is a clear discrepancy between documentation, expectation and the actual behavior here. It needs to be clarified either way. If gcount isn't supposed to increased on EOF, even though a null character was appended, then **how do I get the number of bytes written into the buffer in total**?

Comment: You need to read the full text. Maybe you are even right, but this cherry picking of single sentences will not lead us anywhere. If you think the docs are wrong you need to quote them fully. (And then perhaps its a matter to be discussed on their forums)

Comment: cplusplus is not official documentation. Everybody knows that it is flawed and has serious misinformation, or they will find out at some point. Don't get too hang up by sites spreading wrong information, there are just too many. cppreference is community curated, hence bugs usually don't surive for long.

Comment: fwiw "  ..ive location of the array and updates gcount()" does not mean that `gcount` counts the EOF as +1, it merely means that the call to getline will update gcount even if eof was hit. In some situations hitting eof is considered a fail, so one might expect that gcount still returns number of charcters read by the previous call, but thats not the case

Comment: "how do I get the number of bytes written into the buffer in total?" is that your actual *problem*? It is `gcount` unless you hit eof then it is `gcount +1`. Does that not work for you?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number you are right. I should have asked how to get the number of bytes written into the buffer in total because ultimately that's what really matters even though the "number of characters extracted" is still ambiguous in the documentation and should be targeted in the respective resources. Do you recommend opening a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the last line in your example and walk through it - `yy<eof>`.

```
initial state: gcount = 0, strlen(inProgressBuf) == 0
yy<eof>

gcount = 1, strlen(inProgressBuf) == 1
yy<eof>
^

gcount = 2, strlen(inProgressBuf) == 2
yy<eof>
 ^

oh, hit EOF
yy<eof>
  ^
```

At the point of hitting EOF, two characters have been extracted and so `gcount` is 2. `getline` is now going to append a null character to your buffer - this has nothing to do with `gcount`. Only two characters were actually extracted.

In the case of a string with a delimiter, lets say `yy<lf><eof>`:

```
initial state: gcount = 0, strlen(inProgressBuf) == 0
yy<lf><eof>

gcount = 1, strlen(inProgressBuf) == 1
yy<lf><eof>
^

gcount = 2, strlen(inProgressBuf) == 2
yy<lf><eof>
 ^
gcount = 3, strlen(inProgressBuf) == 2
yy<lf><eof>
  ^
```

When the LF is hit, a character IS being extracted from the input, and so `gcount` is incremented. However, that extracted character matches the `getline` delimiter and so it is NOT added to your buffer. A null character gets added simply for null termination of the string.

`EOF` is not a character that can be extracted and so reaching it does not increment `gcount`.

The only wording I can see on `cppreference` that could maybe be disputed is this excerpt from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline:

> In any case, if count > 0, it then stores a null character CharT() into the next successive location of the array and updates gcount().

You could maybe interpret this as the appending of the null character is why `gcount` is being updated. However, I believe the intended meaning is that `gcount` is being updated because `count > 0`.

Regarding the question of how to determine the number of bytes written, the suggestion in the comments seems appropriate:

> It is `gcount` unless you hit eof then it is `gcount + 1`

Comment: Can we then officially conclude that there is no specified way to get the exact number of bytes written into the array buffer? Any documentation stating that is ill formed. After all, the line delimiter is theoretically not limited to 1 character and could be more (carriage return + line feed, for example), therefore the `gcount + 1` advice is misinformation.

Comment: Could it ever theoretically be that one character is extracted and two bytes are written into the array buffer? If that one character is a 2-byte unicode sequence, it increases `gcount` by 1 but actually 2 bytes are stored? Therefore deriving the number of bytes stored from `gcount` is technically wrong and should be stated everywhere in the documentation.

Comment: I edited the original question quite a lot. I removed the part where I asked how to get the number of bytes written into the array buffer because I intend to create a new question just for that. Please see the end of my question and try to target that too. What is meant by *extraction* and what is meant by a *character* in this context?

Comment: `Could it ever theoretically be that one character is extracted and two bytes are written into the array buffer?` Yes, if your character type `CharT` is a 2-byte type.

Comment: I would completely agree that any documentation stating that `gcount` gets the exact number of bytes written is wrong. Given that was from cpluscplus.com, I am not surprised. I don't agree that `gcount + 1` advice is bad though. You cannot pass a multi-character delimiter to `std::getline`, so the fact that multi-character line endings exist is irrelevant. Everywhere I can see on cppreference states that gcount is the number of `characters`, not bytes.

Extraction is reading the character from the input. `character` is an instance of `CharT`.

Comment: It seems to me that if you disregard anything that `cplusplus.com` says, most of the chance for confusion goes away. `cppreference`, which is the trustworthy source of information here, seems to be accurate and clear in what each of the functions in question do.

Comment: Because you are using `char` as your `CharT`, no you cannot run into situations where one character is extracted and two bytes written because you `CharT` does not support multi-byte character sequences like unicode.